# bitnami wordpress on AWS ec2, suddenly got http error 500 for php pages, why?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My website is built by Bitnami cloud image Wordpress running on AWS ec2 instance (t2-micro, free tier), but these days I got http error 500 so I can not access the web..

If I put an index.html file in the root, the site will display the html file, but just can not display any php files...

My web is built for an activity and these days there are many people visit the site and operate some services on it.(something like uploading images or viewing pages..)

I do not know what is going on..

Do you know any reasons possible which may cause this situation ?

Please help me, thank you very much.

Comment: That error code means there is an error on the server. You would need to ssh into your server and view the logs to see what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 0):

50x error means "Internal server error". 
There are a lot of issues which could cause this issue.
It could be nginx/apache error or most probably it is some kind of php error. 
I would suggest to review server and application logs to find out issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much.

I think I found the reason why my site is down.

It is because the plugin modifications cause the issue.

I have solved it by restoring my original plugin file and the site is back to normal.

Thank you all.